# get all rows with latest previous timestamp in python df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with a datetime64 `time` column. Given a timestamp `t`, I'd like to be able to get all rows with `time` that is closest but before `t`.

Currently, I create a sorted list of `time` (with duplicates removed), get the first timestamp from that list, and then select all rows with this timestamp.

Is there a better way (ie. a vectorized operation) to do this?

For example, given the following dataframe and `t = 1/1/1980 2:00:59`, I want to return `pd.DataFrame([Timestamp('1/1/1980 2:00:00'),2],[Timestamp('1/1/1980 2:00:00'),2])`

| time | some_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/1980 1:00:00 | 1 |
| 1/1/1980 2:00:00 | 2 |
| 1/1/1980 2:00:00 | 3 |
| 1/1/1980 2:01:00 | 4 |

Comment: Can you add sample data an expected output to this question?

Comment: @ScottBoston - added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nearest()` and `apply()` seem to be what you're looking for

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['1/1/1980 1:00:00','1/1/1980 2:00:00','1/1/1980 2:00:00','1/1/1980 2:01:00'], 'some_data':[1,2,3,4]})
>>> df['time'] = df.time.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
>>> df
                 time  some_data
0 1980-01-01 01:00:00          1
1 1980-01-01 02:00:00          2
2 1980-01-01 02:00:00          3
3 1980-01-01 02:01:00          4
>>> target = datetime.strptime('1/1/1980 2:00:59', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
>>> target
datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3)

>>> def nearest(df,t):
...     return df.iloc[df['time'].apply(lambda x: t - x if t > x else np.nan).idxmin()]
>>> nearest(df,target)
time         1980-01-01 02:00:00
some_data                      2
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Based off of [Daniel Aben-Athar Bemerguy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68684913/13112739) and [subsequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68684286/get-all-rows-with-latest-previous-timestamp-in-python-df#comment121443812_68684913) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68684286/get-all-rows-with-latest-previous-timestamp-in-python-df/68719154#comment121445431_68684913)

Answer (score 2):

I´m not very good with dates but here is a solution that might work for you:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['1/1/1980 1:00:00','1/1/1980 2:00:00','1/1/1980 2:01:00']})
```

This will give the following DataFrame

```
0   1980-01-01 01:00:00
1   1980-01-01 02:00:00
2   1980-01-01 02:01:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

```py
target = datetime.strptime('1/1/1980 2:00:03', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

def nearest(df,t):
    return df.iloc[df.apply(lambda x: abs(x - t)).idxmin()]

df = df.time.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

nearest(df,target)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Timestamp('1980-01-01 02:00:00')
```

Comment: this is the correct answer - always use vectorized operations

Comment: Is there any way to get the entire row rather than just the timestamp (faster than just `df[['Time' == nearest(df,target)]]`?

Comment: @user760900 This is actually not correct because it I have `t = 1/1/1980 2:00:59` in the above dataset, this will method will fail

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, this shall anwer your question:

```
import datetime
latest_row=pd.Timestamp.min
count=0
t = "1/1/1980 2:00:03"
t=datetime.datetime.strptime(t,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
def fetch_latest(df_vals,date):
    global latest_row
    count=1
    for row in df.values:
        row_date=row[0]
        if row_date<date:
            if row_date==latest_row:
                count+=1
            if row_date>latest_row:
                count=1
                latest_row=row_date                
    Latest_rows=[latest_row]*count
    return Latest_rows


fetch_latest(df,t)
```

[image]

Comment: This is basically what I already have. I was looking for some vectorized way of doing this